# Python script for upload to server

Tags: python, upload, python-requests

I am new to Python and it is first post. Want to upload a TXT file to server, (as of now, it is local host).Every time, I run the script, the local file uploaded and updated on server. I am using [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org) module

```
import requests, time
url ='http://192.168.49.205/test/database/data.txt'  # where i want to write 
files = {'file':('data.txt','C:\Python27\data.txt','rb')}
#r = requests.post(url,files=files) # this works too

r= requests.post('http://192.168.49.205/test/database/data.txt',
data={'upload_type': 'standard',          'upload_to': '0'},files=files)

print r.status_code
print r.text
```

`data.txt` is not updated. Just seeing old data (I put some values when file created).I am not using any Forms in PHP or HTML. Is it possible to upload with method?

Believe,I got some clarity after posting the question. Now, there is PHP file  on server side listening to client. Here is the "post.php". So, this will replace the text file on Client side. PHP file get the Name, Task, Value from client and post to "a.txt" on server (local)

```
 <?php    
 if(isset($_GET["Name"])){
 $name=$_GET["Name"];   
 }

 if(isset($_GET["Task"])){
 $task=$_GET["Task"];   
 }

if(isset($_GET["Value"])){
$value=$_GET["Value"];   
}

$f=fopen("a.txt","w") or exit("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($f,$name);
fwrite($f,"  ");
fwrite($f,$task);
fwrite($f,"  ");
fwrite($f,$value);
fclose($f);

?>`
```

So now Requests look like this

```
 import requests, time
 url = 'http://192.168.49.205/test/test.php' 
 post_data = {'Name':'job','Task':'008','Value':'8'}

 r= requests.post('http://192.168.49.205/test/post.php', data= post_data)


print r.status_code
print r.text
```

Stil the values is not reaching "a.txt". What i am missing? Please advise!

Comment: The error could be on the server side.

Comment: Does `http://192.168.49.205/test/database/data.txt` accept `POST` requests? What kind of service is listening there?

Comment: data.txt is plain text file. Do not think, it takes POST request or listening.After your question, i getting the idea. So, server file  should be PHP file which accepts  POST request. Please bear my ignorance.

Comment: url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
   files = {'file': open('report.xls', 'rb')}  
   r = requests.post(url, files=files). Here, on the URL what exactly post means? Is it continuously listening part on server?

Comment: There are other methods that may be supported but usually are not. PUT for example should do what you want. http://techforum4u.com/content.php/229-HTTP-Request-GET-HEAD-POST-PUT-DELETE-OPTION-TRACE

Comment: @Lutz: After discussion with my friend, i understand, there is some script should always listening before client make request. So, i have PHP script which receives the data from client. Please refer my updated questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You're not reading the files content in your code. The [requests documentation](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.request) states:

> files – (optional) Dictionary of ‘name’: file-like-objects (or
>   {‘name’: (‘filename’, fileobj)}) for multipart encoding upload.

Your code suggests you want to use the second option. However:

```
files = {'file':('data.txt','C:\Python27\data.txt','rb')}
```

You're **not** creating the structure as the documentation indicates - you're passing a tuple of 3 strings instead of a tuple of (string, file_obj). You probably wanted to do this:

```
files = {'file':('data.txt',open('C:\Python27\data.txt','rb'))}
```